# Sigma field generated by the union of a field and a set

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to show that; If $H$ is a set lying outside a field (or $\sigma$-field) $\mathcal{F}$, then the field (or $\sigma$-field) generated by $\{\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\}\}$ consists of sets of the form; $(H\cap A)\cup (H^{C}\cap B)$, where $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$.

I have found that if $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are fields, then $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\cup \mathcal{F}_2)$ can be written as

$\mathcal{G}=\left\{\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} (A_i\cap B_i): A_i\in \mathcal{F}_1, B_i\in\mathcal{F}_2, (A_i\cap B_i) \text{ are disjoint}\right\}$. $(*)$

I think that $(*)$ will imply the above by setting $\mathcal{F}_2=\{H,\phi\}$, but how can we prove $(*)$?

Comment: $(*)$ isn't even true for just $\sigma(F_1)$ if $F_1$ is only a field.

Comment: Isn't a sigma field of a set (or a class) can be written as a finite union of disjoint intersections?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be closed under countable union.